# Facebook Graph API - Get photos by User Tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-field-expansion

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API v2.3 field expansion to get the photo's of a specific friend from their albums.

I only want a list of all UserA's photos from UserA's albums which have UserB tagged in.

The following returns all of UserA's albums, photos and tags:

`me?fields=albums.limit(25){name,photos.limit(25){name,picture,tags.limit(25)}}`

But I don't know how to apply a where clause / filter the query to only return those where the tags.id = UserB.id.

I can't find anything in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#fieldexpansion), so I suspect I'm approaching it wrong. Is there an available solution or an alternative route which uses a minimal number of API requests?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do additional filterning. You'll have a problem anyway, because you could only access those friends which are also using the same app (and by that, only to a very limited set of information).

The `friends_*` permissions have been removed with the introduction of Graph API v2.0.